# Secure Password storage PHP

Tags: php, sql, security, hash

Is the method I wrote here secure enough for password storage in my database?  I'm not sure if I implemented the pepper correctly, and obviously the salt would be stored in the database.

```
$userPassword = "password";

$pepper = "81521500905970edf70e3017.50852645";
$pepperedPassword = hash_hmac('sha512', $password, $pepper);
$salt = uniqid(random_int(1000000000,9999999999), true);

$options = [
    'cost' => 12,
    'salt' => $salt,
];

$hash = password_hash($pepperedPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);

if (password_verify($userPassword, $hash)) {
      // Login successful.
      echo "Salt:" . $salt . "<BR>";
      echo "Pepper: " . $pepper . "<BR>";
      echo "Peppered password: " . $pepperedpassword . "<BR>";
      echo "Password Hash: " . $hash;

}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a **code review request**. This might be better suited to the [Code Review Stack Exchange site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). Before posting there be sure to read their [FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) to ensure that your question meets their guidelines.

Comment: Why are you generating your own salt? Leave that to `password_hash`, it's one of its main strengths.

Comment: You're not using the peppered password for anything, it's pointless.

Comment: Yea I just realized that typo right after I pasted the code, so other than me forgetting to compare the correct string, and removing the manual salt creation, is this a solid implementation?

Comment: I don't understand the point of the "peppered" password. It wouldn't necessarily make your storage any more secure and more likely make it less by changing the entropy being passed into password_hash.

Comment: It's to make short \ weak passwords stronger against dictionary attacks if they don't have access to the codebase.

Comment: But while it lengthens short passwords, it weakens longer ones. The string you are using with password_hash is longer for most cases, but the value is hex so each character only has 16 possible characters. You are also breaking functions like [password_needs_rehash](https://php.net/password_needs_rehash) because you can essentially never upgrade your sha512 to something else without making your own rehash function. password_hash stores the hash algorithm with the output so you can easily check if the hash is out of date, rehash and update it the database.

Comment: Ahh, that you for the info, like I said I'm new to this and just trying to piece together info from what I'm reading to create a secure system!

Comment: Plus, short passwords will still be easy to lookup. password_hash uses it's own unique salt. Your pepper is using a single salt. Someone could easily make a rainbow table of short/weak passwords and then run them through password hash. It doesn't slow anything down (which is important with proper hashing). It doesn't make anything more secure.

Comment: When it comes to things like secure password storage, etc, it is usually best to just keep it simple and try not to be clever and "help" people out. That usually does the opposite. Have a read of this too: https://blog.codinghorror.com/password-rules-are-bullshit/

Comment: Thank you, I'll read through it, and remove my manual salt creation.  Also would just adding the pepper to the password work (rather than using it to encrypt the string) for what I'm looking to do regarding dictionary attacks?

Comment: Things like the salt (and pepper) really don't much to prevent dictionary attacks. A dictionary attacker will just loop over each password in the dictionary, hash the password matching your scheme and check if it is in the list of hashes. Pretty much no scheme you come up with will prevent this. What the salt does do is prevents rainbow tables. If no salt was used, I could just loop through, hash my password list and store that somewhere. Then comparing an unsalted hash with that list would be a simple lookup that takes a few milliseconds.

Comment: So this wouldn't stop dictionary attacks assuming they didn't have access to the code base?  (code in image) http://imgur.com/PC9fjd7

Comment: Here's some good information about peppers: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/130176/719

Answer (score 1):

No, you're not using `password_hash` as advised by the docs. See the big red box on http://php.net/password_hash - the ability to set a manual salt will go away in a future version, as you should not be doing that.

> **Warning** The salt option has been deprecated as of PHP 7.0.0. It is now preferred to simply use the salt that is generated by default.

Comment: Your code also doesn't make much sense, as you'd typically verify against the hash in the database. Hashing the password and then verifying that hash will always be true and accomplishes nothing.

Comment: Presumably those are separate actions… I hope they are.

Comment: @deceze I'd hope so, but they aren't in the code sample.

Comment: Yes, they are all implemented separately in the actual project, I was just trying to illustrate what I was using to generate the information all in one code sample to see if the encryption \ hashing itself was secure.